# Go AWS SES Unable to find credentials

Tags: go, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to send mail using aws sdk v2 for Go.
I'm getting below error. When using s3 client everything is working fine. I checked the permissions associated with the credentials and it has administrator access. Unable to understand what could be the problem.

```
operation error SES: SendEmail, failed to sign request: failed to retrieve credentials: request canceled, context canceled
```

config.go

```
AWSConfig, err = awsConfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error configuring aws: ", err)
    }
```

mailer.go

```
type Mail struct {
    To []string
    From string
    Subject string
    Body string
}

func (m *Mail) Send(ctx context.Context) error {
    sesClient := ses.NewFromConfig(config.AWSConfig)
    result, err := sesClient.SendEmail(ctx, &ses.SendEmailInput{
        Destination:          &types.Destination{
            ToAddresses:  m.To,
        },
        Message:              &types.Message{
            Body:    &types.Body{
                Html: &types.Content{
                    Data:    &m.Body,
                    Charset: &CharSet,
                },
            },
            Subject: &types.Content{
                Data:    &m.Subject,
                Charset: &CharSet,
            },
        },
        Source:               &m.From,
        ReplyToAddresses:     ReplyTo,
        ReturnPath:           &BounceEmail,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(fmt.Errorf("[MailSenderUtil]: error sending mail: %w", err))
        return err
    }
    log.Println("[MailSenderUtilResult]: ", InJson(result))
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add your aws credentials to config.AWSConfig. This is my config

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(constants.AWSAccessID, constants.AWSAccessKey , ""),
    Region:aws.String("eu-west-2")},
)

svc := ses.New(sess)

input := &ses.SendEmailInput{
    Destination: &ses.Destination{
        ToAddresses: []*string{
            aws.String(Recipient),
        },
    },
    Message: &ses.Message{
        Body: &ses.Body{
            Html: &ses.Content{
                Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
                Data:    aws.String(HtmlBody),
            },
            Text: &ses.Content{
                Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
                Data:    aws.String(TextBody),
            },
        },
        Subject: &ses.Content{
            Charset: aws.String(CharSet),
            Data:    aws.String(Subject),
        },
    },
    Source: aws.String(Sender),
    // Uncomment to use a configuration set
    //ConfigurationSetName: aws.String(ConfigurationSet),
}

// Attempt to send the email.
_, err = svc.SendEmail(input)
if err != nil {
    if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        switch aerr.Code() {
        case ses.ErrCodeMessageRejected:
            logger.Logger.Error(ses.ErrCodeMessageRejected, aerr.OrigErr())
        case ses.ErrCodeMailFromDomainNotVerifiedException:
            logger.Logger.Error(ses.ErrCodeMailFromDomainNotVerifiedException, aerr.OrigErr())
        case ses.ErrCodeConfigurationSetDoesNotExistException:
            logger.Logger.Error(ses.ErrCodeConfigurationSetDoesNotExistException, aerr.OrigErr())
        default:
            logger.Logger.Error("amazon default error", aerr.OrigErr())
        }
    } else {
        logger.Logger.Error("amazon default error (else)", aerr.OrigErr())
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: In almost every case, this is bad advice. The AWS SDK provides numerous mechanisms to load credentials, and will automatically do so assuming that the environment where the application is running has been properly configured.